# is there a way to hide specific parts of a view in ios?

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to know whether a specific portion of a **UI view** can be made hidden.I have a view that is movable.The problem is that when I move the view down the view is visible below safe area.I want to hide the portions of the view that are below safe area.

Comment: use view property clipToBounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you constrain the enclosing view, lets call it simply `view`, of that `movableView` to the `safeArea`, the easiest way would be to simple set:

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

This will prevent drawing any of the `view` contents outside of its bounds. So if `movableView` is its subview somewhere in the hierarchy, and its part moves out of the bounds (i.e. below the `safeArea`), the part outside will be clipped and not rendered.

If not don't have such a view yet, adding a transparent view (`backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`) that would be constrained as such with its `clipsToBounds` set to `true` would solve it for your.

Comment: Works as expected.Thanks